# OpenBlas Android slow for large matrix

Tags: android, openblas

Trying to port openblas for android.
the openblas for android took from here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.8-arm/openblas-v0.2.8-android-rc1.tar.gz/download.
This is my time measures for cblas_sgemm

```
1. android  samsung s6
         0.003 s for 100x100  sgemm
         3.130 s for 1000X1000  sgemm
2. windows x64 intel i5
         0.001 s for 100x100  sgemm
         0.080 s for 1000X1000  sgemm
```

What causing to openblas run so slow with 1000X1000 matrix in android.
How i can improve it?

Comment: two reasons: the processor is not nearly as powerful and there is much less main memory which causes swapping.

Comment: You right it is main memory.I used 64 bit compilation for armv8 and execution times now comparable for andoird and windows.